# Create argument string from argv

Tags: c++, winapi

I have program in c/c++ and I want to relaunch it using ShellExecuteEx function with almost same arguments that were passed to my program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

In my case I need to modify one argv and together with the rest of the argvs I want to join them into single string. However, in argv there can be spaces, special characters... What is the proper way to create argument string from argv array?

Comment: Use `GetCommandLine()`.

Comment: What is C/C++ ?

Comment: GetCommandLine is good, thanks, but what if I want to manually loop through argv and create argument string? Is it enough to wrap individual arguments into quotes "?

Comment: Nope, that's not enough. See dupe.

Comment: If you need to pass *"exactly [the] same arguments"*, calling `GetCommandLine()` is the correct solution. It's unclear why you believe that you have to iterate over the **processed** arguments, essentially undoing the processing. You already have a solution, why complicate things?

Comment: I edited my question: In my case I need to modify one argv and together with the rest of the argvs I want to join them into single string.

Comment: if you *relaunch* self exe and want pass information to new exec - the best get command line string via *GetCommandLineW()* and *append* to the end your extraparameter, in your private format